# Ansible Failed to get information on remote file /etc/environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ansible, ubuntu-22.04

I'm creating an `ec2` with `ubuntu 22.04` using ansible.

I need to copy a local file to `/etc/environment` but I always get `Failed to get information on remote file /etc/environment`.
I've tryed to use `become` but it doesn't works.

This is my playbook:

```
- name: deploy everything
  hosts: all
  remote_user: ubuntu
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND: noninteractive

  pre_tasks:
    - name: 'update'
      raw: sudo apt-get -y update
    
    - name: 'upgrade'
      raw: sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" upgrade

    - name: 'install Python3 part 1'
      raw: sudo apt-get -y update && sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y python3-simplejson

    - name: 'Install Python3 part 2'
      raw: test -e /usr/bin/python3 || (apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y python3-minimal)

    - name: 'Configure environment'
      copy:
        src: environment
        dest: /etc/environment
```

What am I wrong?

Thank you

Here the complete error:

```
{"type":"log",
"content":"fatal: [IP]: FAILED! => 
    {\"msg\": \"Failed to get information on remote file 
     (\/var\/environment): Shared connection to *IP* 
     closed.\\r\\n\"}\n"},
    {"type":"log",
    "content":"\tto retry, use: --limit @\/var\/tmp\/sysadmin\/architecture\/64887bcd740cc\/launch.retry\n\nPLAY RECAP *********************************************************************\nIP: ok=4    changed=4    unreachable=0    failed=1"}
```

Comment: Can you copy and paste the complete error message? There is generally something after the `failed to get information on remote file ...` part that may help diagnose the problem. Why are you using the `raw` module here rather than `command` or even better the `package` module?

Comment: The problem is ubuntu 22.04. If I try with a remote machine ubuntu 18 it works, but if I try on remote machine with ubuntu 22 I have this error.
The permissions of the file and the folder (/etc) is the same on ubuntu 18 and 22

Comment: Anyone have an idea?